# T-SQL: Insert Into Random Values Linked

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good Morning,

I have a created a test database with 6 tables which I want to link all together in my 'master table', Car_Spec.

I want my table 'Car_Spec' to automatically populate the 'Manufacutre_ID' field based on what is in to 'Model' field.

*I.e. if the Model_ID is 104 (panda) then I want the manufacture_ID to be 102 (Fiat).*

I have just created my database and tables using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE car_manufacture
(
    manufacture_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1),
    manufacture_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    manufacture_Country varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(manufacture_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE car_model
(
    model_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1),
    manufacture_ID INT,
    model_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (model_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (manufacture_ID) REFERENCES car_manufacture (manufacture_ID),
)

CREATE TABLE car_drive
(
    drive_ID int NOT NULL,
    drive_side varchar(10)
    PRIMARY KEY (drive_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE car_litre
(
    litre_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1),
    litre int,
    PRIMARY KEY (litre_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE car_fueltype
(
    fuel_ID INT NOT NULL,
    fuel VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (fuel_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE car_spec
(
    car_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (100,1),
    manufacture_ID INT NOT NULL,
    model_ID INT NOT NULL,
    drive_ID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
    fuel_ID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
    age INT,
    miles INT,
    registration VARCHAR (10),
    previous_owners INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (car_ID),

    FOREIGN KEY (manufacture_ID) REFERENCES car_manufacture (manufacture_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (model_ID) REFERENCES car_model(model_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (drive_ID) REFERENCES car_drive (drive_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (fuel_ID) REFERENCES car_fueltype(fuel_ID)
)
```

I have populated all but the last table using the following code also:

```
INSERT INTO car_manufacture (manufacture_Name, manufacture_Country) VALUES 

    ('Volkswagen',  'Germany'),
    ('Fiat',        'Italy'),
    ('Seat',        'Spain'),
    ('Ford',        'American')

INSERT INTO car_model (manufacture_ID,model_name)VALUES

    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Volkswagen'),'Polo'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Volkswagen'),'Golf'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Fiat'),'Panda'), 
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Fiat'),'Punto'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Seat'),'Ibiza'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Seat'),'Leon'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Fiat'),'500'),
    ((Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacture where manufacture_Name = 'Volkswagen'),'Passat')

INSERT INTO car_drive (drive_ID, drive_side)VALUES
    (1, 'Left'),
    (2, 'Right'),
    (3, 'Unknown')

INSERT INTO car_litre (litre) Values
    (1),
    (1.2),
    (1.4),
    (1.6),
    (1.8),
    (2)

INSERT INTO car_fueltype (fuel_id,fuel) values
(1,'Petrol)'), 
(2,'Diesel'),
(3,'Gas'), 
(4,'Unknown')
```

This is where I get stuck...

```
Insert into car_spec (age, car_ID, drive_ID, fuel_ID, manufacture_ID, miles, model_ID, previous_owners, registration)
Values

    (
        3, 
        (select TOP 1 model_ID from car_model ORDER BY NEWID()), 
        (select TOP 1 drive_ID from car_drive ORDER BY NEWID()),
        (select TOP 1 fuel from car_fueltype ORDER BY NEWID()),
        **THIS IS WHERE I WANT A STATEMENT 'Select manufacture_ID from car_manufacutre based on model_ID,', **
```

Car ID = Model ID.

Any advise would be greatful, I thought about using Variables, but again, not sure how that would work. I think an InnerJoin will solve the issue, but I can't work it out.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`.  Then you have more control over the data.  The query would look like this:

```
Insert into car_spec(age, car_ID, drive_ID, fuel_ID, manufacture_ID, 
                     miles, model_ID, previous_owners, registration
                    )
    select t.age, t.model_id, t.drive_id, d.fuel_id, cm.manufacturer_id, 
           . . .
    from (select 3 as age, 
                 (select TOP 1 model_ID from car_model ORDER BY NEWID()) as model_id,
                 (select TOP 1 drive_ID from car_drive ORDER BY NEWID()) as drive_id,
                 (select TOP 1 fuel from car_fueltype ORDER BY NEWID()) as fuel_id
         ) t join
         car_model cm 
         on t.model_id = cm.model_id;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,I don't think this answers my question.

I want car manufacture be be involed with this as well but the value to be linked with car_model as they are linked together.

Comment: Ignore the above. I've just realised what you did. I will test this and post my results.

Comment: @SamCramphorn . . . You can delete your own comment.